# HDMI connection between HD TV and Asus ME 302C

Tags: hdmi

Will a HDMI cable with Standard male connector on one end for a HD TV, and a  Micro HDMI connector on the other to connect to my Asus ME 302c tablet allow me to view photos and video from my tablet on my TV? or do I need some special cables or devices?

Comment: Related [Connecting Samsung Galaxy Note to TV](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19676/209414)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a HDMI to Micro-HDMI cable, just plug the tablet into the TV and select the HDMI input on the TV. It will mirror the tablet display on the TV.