# Share contents between my Galaxy Note 5 and Samsung Smart TV

Tags: smart-tv, samsung-galaxy-note-5, screen-mirroring

I used to have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 a few years ago, I remember I could connect my phone with my 8880 Samsung Smart TV.

This connection was two way, I used screen mirroring so I could display phone contents on the TV, and I could watch TV programs on my phone.

I even remember once my wife was watching TV and I watched another program on another channel using my phone (connected to TV).

Unfortunately I can't remember the application names which provided these features.

Its now two years that I have changed my phone with a Galaxy Note 5, and I have done all the upgrades. The problem is I can not do what I did with the old version of mobile set. I believe I don't have the applications, and I can't remember their names.

By the way is there any way so I can screen mirror a video played using streaming (is not on my phone but it is online) on my TV? Because Samsung Smart View application just shares contents (videos/photos/music) which are stored in my gallery.

Comment: See if this helps: [Connecting Samsung Galaxy Note to TV](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19676/209414)

Comment: @xavier_fakerat There is a `Smart View` option on the phone. There is a `Nearby device scanning` option in the settings, which says that **Nearby device scanning uses Bluetooth Low Energy Scanning and the microphone. Bluetooth Low Energy scanning can be used even while Bluetooth is turned off on this device.** And it is turned on!

Comment: I meant quick connect.  Quick connect will use the Bluetooth® feature, Wi-Fi Direct®, or Screen Mirroring, depending on the type of content being shared and whether the other device has Quick connect installed. https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00043278/

Comment: @xavier_fakerat The thing is I did screen mirroring from phone to tv and from tv to phone with my Galaxy Note 3. Now I have Galaxy Note 5 and I can't remember the software names (and availability) of the same things.

Comment: Aww I see, that feature was built in in earlier editions of Samsung Note phones, but was removed, so you have to install a third party app from playstore

Comment: I can not find Quick Connect on my phone. And yes I am looking for the apps, they were manufactured by Samsung, but I can not find them on Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

Screen mirroring is a feature available on some editions of Samunng Smartphones, but unfortunately has been removed in later builds on smartphones and replaced  Samsung Smart View and related.

> Using the Screen Mirroring feature, you can share your Galaxy device’s
>   screen with your Samsung Smart TV or with an HDTV using the **AllShare
>   Cast** Wireless Hub.

The following [phones support](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/51287/how-do-i-mirror-my-samsung-galaxy-phones-screen-on-my-tv/) the Screen Mirroring feature by default. Some phones can be modified through a custom ROM, so they also may be able to support screen mirroring.

- Samsung Galaxy S3, S4 ,S5
- Samsung Galaxy Note 2, 3, 4

Nevertheless you can use alternatives app to achieve the same e.g [Screen Mirroring](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=screenmirroring.abdelm.com.screenmirroring&hl=en) from Playstore.

Another aggressive way of enabling the feature in Note 5 is perhaps rooting and editing build.prop line: `wlan.wfd.hdcp=disable` (anywhere within the additional build properties section, preferably at the end)
under `/Device/system` folder. (Remember to save and reboot) as outlined [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/note5/help/note-5-screen-mirroring-problem-t3195134/page3) on XDA thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I prefer not to root my phone. So I go after software solutions. By the way is there any app which let me watch TV channels on my phone?

Comment: Yes there are plenty, for starters see [Kodi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kodi) which is an open-source media center